# routerLinkActive class dosen't apply if there is already a class present to that component

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular8, angular-routerlink, routerlinkactive

I came across a wired problem where I have an angular material sidebar and in that I have buttons used for routing the applications let me put the code below

```
<div fxLayoutAlign="start stretch">
      <button routerLinkActive="selected"  [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}" (click)="btnclick('faculty')" mat-flat-button routerLink="/mainview/faculty">
        {{'sidebar.faculty' | translate}}
      </button>
    </div>
```

so I use button with the applied default style as below in css file

```
.example-container button{
    color: #DCDCDC;
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    background-color: #483d8b;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: lighter;
  }
```

and below is the style I want to apply when the routerLink is Active

```
.selected{
    color: white;
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    background-color: #483d8b;
    font-weight: 500;
  }
```

but the selected style is not getting applied I tried various hacks to apply it but couldn't work like
using routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive" and applying that condition in ngclass etc etc

But I came to see the special behaviour that It works if I remove the default style...!!!

I don't know the the reason why but It works if I remove the default button style.

So can anyone help me to figure out what exactly is needed for this solution as I searched for the similar post but none worked for me..!!

Comment: Might this be a CSS specificity problem? What happens if you replace `.selected { ... }` with `.example-container button.selected { ... }`

Comment: yes It worked as you suggested thanks a ton please write it in answer with some explanation I will be glad to approve it..!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a CSS specificity problem.

You might want to have a look at these 2 articles which explain this topic very well:

- [Specifics on CSS Specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)
- [CSS Specificity: Things You Should Know](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)

In this case, `.example-container button` is more *explicit* than `.selector` because the first selector has a class and an element(0011), whereas the second one has only a class(0010).

A solution would be to make the second selector more specific:

```css
.example-container button.selected { ... }
```

which has 2 classes and one element.